# ESLint error trying to deploy functions Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, eslint, firebase-cli

I'm try to deploy fireabase example , but when I try to deploy it , CLI launches an error:

[CODE]

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions'); //to activate firebase functions

const admin = require('firebase-admin'); //to active firebase database permissions

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
// [END addMessageTrigger]
  // Grab the text parameter.
  const original = req.query.text;
  // [START adminSdkPush]
  // Push the new message into the Realtime Database using the Firebase Admin SDK.
  admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: original}).then(snapshot => {
    // Redirect with 303 SEE OTHER to the URL of the pushed object in the Firebase console.
    res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref);
  });
  // [END adminSdkPush]
});
```

[ERROR]

```
  15:3   error  Expected catch() or return                  promise/catch-or-return
  15:69  error  Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return

✖ 2 problems (2 errors, 0 warnings)


npm ERR! Darwin 17.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "--prefix" "/Users/user/test/functions" "run" "lint"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script 'eslint .'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the functions package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     eslint .
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs functions
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls functions
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/eliassebastian/Developer/npm-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

I take a look to original final provided by firebase [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/uppercase/functions/index.js#L29-L43)

I'm to new in Javascript and all this world, so I'm really lost with this type of messages.

How can I solve this?

Comment: There are many messages here for different concerns. *"Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed."* seems clear enough.

Comment: d'ouh totally my fault. Can we close it. Thanks @DenysSéguret

Comment: Even if npm errors are resolved, _the eslint warnings are legit_ and will continue to prevent the code from being deployed.  Definitely need to resolve those.

Comment: I got these error while deploying on firebase

  57:14  warning  Unexpected function expression  prefer-arrow-callback
  61:12  error    'ref' is already defined        no-redeclare

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The ESLint warnings are legitimate.  To get more detail on each one, you can search them using their unique id.  For example:

```
15:3   error  Expected catch() or return                  promise/catch-or-return
```

The id of the warning here is `promise/catch-or-return`.  Googling for "eslint promise/catch-or-return" finds [a plugin for ESLint](https://github.com/xjamundx/eslint-plugin-promise) that describes the warning as:

> Enforces the use of catch() on un-returned promises

You're getting this because you have a promise being returned from `then`, but you never `return` or `catch` for possible errors.

The second warning:

```
15:69  error  Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return
```

comes from the same ESLint plugin, and is described like this:

> Return inside each then() to create readable and reusable Promise chains.

It's requiring you to return a value inside each function called by `then`, even if you don't have anything special to sent to the next promise chain.

You can resolve both of these problems like this:

```
admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: original}).then(snapshot => {
    res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref);
    return null;
}).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    res.error(500);
});
```

Notice that the `then` block returns null now, and `catch` is used on the promise returned from `then` to capture errors and send an error response to the client.

Answer (score 0):

**Doug Stevenson** answer is partially right as there is one flaw in it.

It should be :

```
admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: original}).then(snapshot => {
    res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref);
    return 1; // IT SHOULD RETURN NON-NULL VALUE
}).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    res.error(500);
});
```

[image: cloud functions issue resolved]

The cloud function went into **infinite loop when it returned null**. And as a result, we can see function timed out after 60,000 ms in the above image.

[image: functions not executed]

After such multiple timed out functions, you will get the error **functions can be executed** (shown in above pic). This is because in Spark Plan (free tier plan), there is limit on *CPUMilliSecondsDailyNonbillable* .

[image: GCD quota area]
If you click on [Stackdriver's Quota Policy](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) in cloud functions section, you can see the limit in GCD( Google Cloud Platform)