# How to fetch firebase database data in cloud function?

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase database to store my iOS app data.

[image]

I am saving user tracking data in this app which is working fine.

I have to send a push notification to the user (userID = 57411405) using push token which I am saving in 'IOS' field.

This cloud function I am using :

This cloud function is working fine. I am able to track event which save new tracking data. Here is log of this cloud function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

exports.databasechanges = functions.database.ref('/users/{id}/LocationTracking').onWrite(event =>{

var eventSnapshot = event.data

console.log('UserId - ', event.params.id);

const userID = event.params.id
const root = event.data.ref.root

admin.database().ref('users/{id}/NotificationToken').on('value').then((snapshot) => {

  var token = snapshot.val().IOS;

  console.log('token',token)

  return snapshot.val();
}).catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
  res.error(500);
});

return eventSnapshot.val()

});
```

But on cloud function console I am getting this error:

[image]
Now, I am not able to figure out how to access this push token (IOS) and send push notification using cloud function.

Comment: Please don't show images of code.  It's far better to copy the code into the question into a code block so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: @DougStevenson I edited my question with more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the field "IOS", try this:

```
//inside the trigger function
admin.database().ref('/users/'+event.params.id+'/NotificationToken/IOS').once('v‌​alue').then((snapshot) => { 
var token=snapshot.val().IOS;

 });
```

Comment: I am getting this error:   24:1  error  Expected catch() or return  promise/catch-or-return

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48582278/eslint-error-trying-to-deploy-functions-firebase

Comment: Cloud function has deployed successfully but I am getting error in cloud function console. I edited my question please have a look.

Comment: @ajeetsharma use once() instead of on() and get the value once

Comment: it's not working :( . getting this error in console:            
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'IOS' of null
    at admin.database.ref.once.then (/user_code/index.js:34:29)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)