# Saving string in Firebase functions using FIrebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am wanting to save one simple string in firebase database from using firebase functions. I have this working and saving the string "THIS NEW CODE". What is simplest way to retrieve this string?

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var ref = admin.database().ref("key").set("THIS NEW CODE");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
admin.database().ref("key").once('value').then(snap => {
    const string = snap.val()
})
```

You should probably familiarize yourself with the [documentation for the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start).

Comment: im getting the same 2 errors as this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48582278/eslint-error-trying-to-deploy-functions-firebase?rq=1 using solution in link i get error: Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return ive been trying to add a return null; to the answer above, it gets the 2 errors

Comment: You're going to have to learn asynchronous programming with JavaScript promises in order to be effective at writing Cloud Functions.

Comment: ref.once("value", function(data) {
  // do some stuff once
});
in the documentation link works, should be using the arrow function instead?

Comment: im new to javascript. ive been trying to follow a long with your videos, the typescript transition has slowed me with the videos. i appriciate the approach in your videos!